# Converting Classic ASP / .NET hybrid web site project to MVC web application project in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, web-applications

I am currently trying to migrate a website project with Classic ASP and .NET files into a new MVC web application project and start using GIT (using GIT extensions/tortoiseGIT/etc).  The goal is to eventually convert all the functionality to MVC.

The site is 5+ years old and has over 210,000 files including classic ASP includes, images, videos, etc.  The total size is over 10GB.  Most of the content has been moved to separate media servers, so that is actually what is left.

I have already created the MVC 3 project and broke out my App_code classes into a separate class library.  After adding a bunch of references, that part seems to be working properly.

Should I add all the thousands of images and such to VS2010 and GIT?  Will they be able to handle that kind of volume or should I take a different approach?

Answer (score 4):

You start with launching Visual Studio 2010 and creating a new ASP.NET MVC 3 project using the default template. In advance you have thought about how you would organize your view models, controllers, views and data access layer. You have drawn diagrams that will help you facilitate through the development process. You have analyzed if there are any *reusable* parts of those 250,000 lines of code or is it all garbage.

Then you can define expectations, write unit tests, ... classic development lifecycle. Also setup your Git repository as early as possible in your development process, at best after creating the project template, and put this template under source control immediately. Also don't forget to setup your continuous integration build server as early as possible so that you are notified of build failures in the *trunk*.

Comment: lol!  I added some more details above.  Mainly I am worried about how to effectively manage such a large number of files in VS/GIT and wondering if it is even practical?

Comment: @Developr, don't be worried about this, GIT manages the source code of the Linux kernel, so your 250,000 lines of code will be easy peasy. Obviously when you migrate to ASP.NET MVC 3 promise me to reduce them at least to half of that :-)

Comment: not lines of code.... 200k + mostly of image files and such (>10gb) and mainly concerned about VS2010....

Comment: @Developr, oops, didn't read carefully. IMHO, you should add those to version control as well.

Answer (score 0):

Also, not a "real" answer or what you wanted to hear, but this is gigantic and will cause you so much trouble, that I'd actually move away from the thought of "migration", it would actually and probably result in a complete rewrite of the functionality, since ASP.NET MVC follows a very different approach of workflow, user controls or data presentation.

Comment: I already have the few .NET pages working in tandem with the existing classic ASP solution... just want to stop using web forms and move to MVC.  My main concern is dealing with so many files in GIT/VS.  "Complete Rewrite" is just not a option at this point...have to evolve or it will never happen.  Looking for advice on how to work with the files.  Should I just keep the .NET/MVC by itself in a separate website project and migrate in section by section or is there a better way?  Can GIT/VS2010 handle that many files or will it be unmanagable?

Comment: I cannot answer specific GIT questions since I'm using TFS, but I'd never add content files to GIT. The main advantage of MVC is the pattern itself, what you're doing here is running ASP in a MVC environment/mode and that won't replace a true MVC approach.

Comment: I intend to replace all the web forms and classic asp files with MVC, but it will have to be section by section.

Answer (score 0):

"Should I add all the thousands of images and such to VS2010 and GIT?"

No.

"Will they be able to handle that kind of volume or should I take a different approach?"

Manage source code with GIT and VS2010. Manage content with a CMS or the file system.

Comment: Why use visual studio as a CMS? It will just crush it under the volume and make everything slow and painful. You may techically be able to do this, but why store resources like images, videos, etc. in your development environment?

Comment: no, not VS, the VCS. Of course that you should never add 250k file to VS. That would be suicidal indeed.

Comment: I think for something of this scale you would want to use a separate tool to manage content.